# The most recent files in directory with a specific format in each one

Tags: shell-script, files, find, ls

I would like to have in a variable the most recent file with a specific format.

**exemple** : in /home/test, 5 files :

- **file_test_hadoop_20181130.csv** (This is the last modified one for hadoop file)
- file_test_hadoop_20181130.txt
- file_test_hadoop_20181130.ini
- **file_test_hub_20181130.txt** (This is the last modified one for txt file)
- file_test_hub_20181130.csv
- file_test_hub_20181130.ini

So the result that i want is the last modified one in each type :
HADOOP_NAME=**file_test_hadoop_20181130.csv**
HUB_NAME=**file_test_hub_20181130.txt**

So i started to do something like this :

**HADOOP_NAM**E=$(ls -tr /home/test | tail -n 1 | find /home/test -maxdepth 1 -name "file_test_hadoop*" -printf '%f\n')

**HUB_NAME**=$(ls -tr /home/test | tail -n 1 | find /home/test -maxdepth 1 -name "file_test_hub*" -printf '%f\n')

But i get all files.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to retrieve the most recently modified file with a specific naming pattern. The following commands should work for you:

```
[haxiel@testvm1 ~]$ ls -1t file_test_hadoop* | head -n1
file_test_hadoop_20181130.csv

[haxiel@testvm1 ~]$ ls -1t file_test_hub* | head -n1
file_test_hub_20181130.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below  command  and it worked fine

```
ls -ltrh /home/test/file_test_hadoop*| tail -n1
ls -ltrh /home/test/file_test_hub* | tail -n1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to parse ls or pipe ls to find & print, just use bash arrays, shell globbing, and the natural sorting order of YYYYMMDD:

```
cd /home/test
hadoop_files=(file_test_hadoop*)
HADOOP_NAME=${hadoop_files[-1]}
unset hadoop_files
hub_files=(file_test_hub*)
HUB_NAME=${hub_files[-1]}
unset hub_files
cd -
```

This populates temporary array variables with the list of filenames that match the various patterns. You'd want to add error-checking for the situations where there are no files at all, or files of an unexpected pattern (file_test_hadoop9, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Your first command

```
ls -tr
```

, correctly lists the files by time

When you pipe that to

```
tail -n1
```

It correctly selects the last entry, the most recent file

Problem is it may or may not be matching your file pattern

Of course, your last command simply does not receive any input from the previous ones
and so it runs simply as it ought to and it lists all the files

```
find /home/test -maxdepth 1 -name "file_test_hadoop*" -printf '%f\n'
```

To solve this, I would first begin with `ls` and `grep` to match the correct pattern, i.e

```
ls -tr | grep "file_test_hadoop" > File_List.txt
```

This would create a file with a list and latest file being at the most bottom,

```
tail -n1 File_List.txt
```

So your code would be `HADOOP_NAME="$(tail -n1 File_List.txt)"`